# ¿Se puede cambiar de una pagina .html a otra pagina .php con href?

Tags: php, html

Soy nuevo en html y tengo una pagina con extensión html y otra con extensión php desde la pagina con extensión .html intente utilizar un href para pasar a la pagina .php pero esta solo me descarga el archivo. ¿hay alguna forma de cambiar de paginas desde un html a un php?

Comment: Claro que es posible, si te la descargo es por qué solo estás abriendo directamente tus páginas y no accedes a ellas desde un servidor, cual usas?

Comment: estoy utilizando el xampp y las paginas están guardadas en el htdocs